# category-slug.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress, view, categories

Here is my code:

```
$config = array(
    'labels'            => $genre_labels,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'htfiles-genre' ),
    );

register_taxonomy('htfiles_genre', array('htfiles'), $config);
```

I create in theme phpfile :

```
Category-htfiles-genre.php
category-{slug}.php
```

– If the category’s slug is htfiles-genre, WordPress shuld look for category-htfiles-genre.php.
but he didn't.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've posted is used to register a custom taxonomy which follows a different naming structure to regular categories.

To display a template file for the taxonomy, you need to use `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`. If you wanted to create a template for a given term in that taxonomy, you would use: `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php`.

Your filename should be: `taxonomy-htfiles_genre.php`.

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies

Answer (score 1):

// You need to save Permalinks again and create following file taxonomy-htfiles_genre.php . Everything will work fine.